# Trouble implementing Keyboard actions

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, action, keyboard-events

I don't get how do implement Keyboard actions at all.

Mouse clicks, Buttons, Textfield, Textarea I get just fine, Keyboard is like the Chinese wall to me.

I have something like this, and I'd like to implement the Keyboard to close when I press "C":

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestGUI
{
    private KeyboardListener anEventListener;

    public TestGUI()
    {
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI()
    {       
        //Prepare Frame
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setTitle("Test");
        myFrame.setSize(550, 500);
        myFrame.setLocation(600, 100);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setLayout(null);

        KeyboardListener anEventListener = new KeyboardListener();

        //Show Frame
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                new TestGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    class KeyboardListener implements KeyListener
    {

      public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event)
      { 
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C)
        { 
            System.exit(0);
        }
      }          

      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
      {

      }
      public void keyTyped (KeyEvent event)
      {

      }
    } 



}
```

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to use Key Bindings.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by checking out [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). This is more reliable than `KeyListeners` as it doesn't have many focus issues. Also, `KeyListeners` is an old AWT solution for problems like this.

Comment: +1, for promoting Key Bindings, which everybody should know about.

Comment: Later maybe. I'm just starting.

Comment: The point is to learn proper coding techniques when you start so you don't learn bad habits. Your next question will be why doesn't the KeyListener work, when I add components to my frame.

Answer (score 3):

> and I'd like to implement the Keyboard to close when I press "C":

Then you should create a custom Action and use a JMenu with a close menu item and an accelerator.

The `ExitAction` from [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't attached your `KeyboardListener` to a component. You also aren't using the `anEventListener` field defined in your class -- it's being shadowed inside `initGUI`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the line

```
myFrame.addKeyListener(anEventListener);
```

to register your listener within your frame and it will work fine.

Note: This will only handle the key events associated with your frame. If you have other components around you might want to handle it differently (see also [how to use key bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)).

In your case you can build a version with key bindings quite easily:

```
JComponent rootPane = myFrame.getRootPane();
rootPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("C"), "closeThisOne");
rootPane.getActionMap().put("closeThisOne", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: This will NOT work, once you actually add compoennts to the frame.

Comment: And how do I do this if other components are in the Frame? Say 2 JButtons and 1 JLabel? I still want the window to close when I press "C".

Comment: The easiest way is to use a JMenuItem as I suggested, which creates a Key Binding for you automatically behind the scenes. Or you can create a Key Binding directly. Also, you would not just listen for the "C". You typically listen for "Alt+C" or whatever the key combination is used for the LAF.

Comment: That doesn't help me at all. I don't want to look up another topic when I don't understand what I've posted just yet. I want to understand and work with what I have then moving on to the next topic i.e. Keybinds. For now I want my method somehow to work if I have a JPanel and 2 JButtons. Whenever I press "c" I want the window completely to close.

Comment: Key events are only dispatched to the component with focus. So you would need to add the listener to every component on the frame. This is why other approaches are recommended because they are simpler to implement and part of standard Swing design. Also, what happens when you enter a text field to the frame and try to type a "C". Does the "C" get added to the text field or close the frame. Again, that is why "Alt+C" (or equivalent) would be used. Many people have spent many hours developing standard GUI interfaces, don't reinvent the wheel!